# swift - declaring computed properties to call a function with multiple return values

Tags: ios, xcode, function, swift, properties

I want to declare 3 computed properties that will call a function calculate that will return multiple values to the 3 computed properties. i.e. fbound1, fbound2 and [displacement] as properties that take values from a function: "calculate" which returns 3 values.

**Code for calculate function with 3 return values**

```
public func calculateBoundary (inout f:[Float], s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> (forceBound1:Float, forceBound2: Float, displacement:[Float])
```

For example, i could declare a computed property that will call 'calculate' function with its return value to be initialized to the property.

**Declaring a computed property that will call calculate function with single return value**

```
var springDisplacement : [Float] {return calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2) }

public func calculate (f:[Float], s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> [Float]
```

Comment: Your second example is not “initialising a single variable”, it is declaring a **computed property** that will call the `calculate` function each time it's accessed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
let (forceBound1, forceBound2, displacement) = calculateBoundary(...)
```

Comment: Error: _'ViewController2.Type' does not have a member named 'forceView2'_

Comment: You're probably inserting your code at the wrong place. It works for me.

Comment: This works only if i put it inside viewdidload method which create these 3 constants are only accessible inside viewdidload method. However i want these 3 to be properties, that other methods can access them. i.e this has to be outside viewdidload method, which gives the error.

Comment: Then you're not trying to assign **variables**, but **properties** (or **fields**, in some other languages). You should rephrase your question.